# Making guides for function template argument deduction in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Before anyone says that this question is duplicate... I checked the other question and that didn't satisfy me. It was not what I was looking for.

1. Is it possible to have argument deduction guides for function templates ?
2. If yes then how ?
   It will be appreciated if someone can give easy examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I checked the other question* Better link it so we know what question you're talking about.

Comment: what about the other question / answers did not satisfy you? If the answer was "no" then asking again will not get you a more satisfying answer

Comment: maybe I am missing some new feature, but I dont understand what a deduction guide for a function template should be. They exist in the context of CTAD and help to get something done that only needs to be done in the context of CTAD because somehow one needs to deduce the type of the class from the parameters to its constructor. What do you expect to get from a deduction guide when its not for that?

Comment: Deduction guides work on on the principles of function overloading. The guide is an "extra overload" whose return type can be examined. For function templates, you could always add overloads.

Comment: So, like we can't have deduction guides for function templates ?

Comment: Functions already do deduction. Why would you need a guide? Can you give an example?

Comment: @RaymondChen I overloaded +operator and used function template so that it works on all data types but automatic deduction won't work on strings (const char *) so I manually overload that case but I thought maybe another way is possible or not. Turns out there are some sneaks but they are just worse than writing 1 more mere overload.

Comment: You should put this information in the question, rather than asking a much more general (and confusing) question. "I want to write an overloaded `+` that does blah blah. I can write blah blah, but it doesn't work when I pass blah blah..."

Comment: Well actually it worked but for some particular reasons I am not posting that. Like I should not. Well anyways I got the answer.

Comment: I'm even more confused now. You said "Well actually it worked". If it worked, then why ask a question?

Comment: Look I am a beginner. I was just exploring the options. I just has been a month or two since I started. 

Comment: It's fine to be a beginner. We were all beginners at some point. But you should work on making your questions more clear. Give specific examples of what you want to do, what you tried, and what didn't work. Otherwise, we don't understand what your question is (or in this case, whether there is even a question at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got the answer actually functions can't have deduction guides. It only works with class templates. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: I realize it's an old question, but it would be nice if you posted your solution so other people who may have the same question can benefit as well.